# javascript code is only work in jquery 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently use lastest jquery in my bootstrap but my javascript code is not working and lastest jquery. It's only work in jquery 1.7.2 but bootstrap need jquery 1.9.1 at least. What wrong with my code? Which part I need to change ?

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input:radio[name='highlight']").on('change',function(){
    if ($('#radio7').attr("checked")){
      $("#additional-service").addClass('shadow');
    } else {
      $("#additional-service").removeClass('shadow');
    }
  });

  $("input:radio[name='highlight']").on('change',function(){
    if ($('#radio8').attr("checked")){
      $("#additional-service1").addClass('shadow');
    } else {
      $("#additional-service1").removeClass('shadow');
    }
  });

  $("input:radio[name='highlight']").on('change',function(){
    if ($('#radio9').attr("checked")){
      $("#additional-service2").addClass('shadow');
    } else {
      $("#additional-service2").removeClass('shadow');
    }
  });
});
```

//]]>

Comment: What errors are showing in the console?  And why are you doing the same binding three times?

Comment: Errors message is nothing special bro. It's only show bootstrap need jquery 1.9.1 at least. Acutally I'm not pro bro :D. I don't know why use binding same times. I just need to do add class when radio button is check.

Comment: open any console debugger and see if errors comes out.
Not always what you write is the right method to access them.Can you post the console errors?

Comment: So it may be that bootstrap is doing a check against `jQuery.fn.jquery` to see if it is a version that it needs and if not it just does not proceed further.  If that is the case, it isn't really an issue.  You just need to use the correct jQuery version for bootstrap.  And you should consolidate those bindings.  *just cause* isn't a good answer to a logical question.

Comment: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4 and TypeError: $.expr.pseudos is undefined[Learn More] when i add 1.7.2 version jquery and bootstrap.min.js is not work. when i add laster version my code is not work :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to check wether some radio inputs are checked.
You can't do that with `.attr()` with recent jQuery versions,  you should use `.prop()` instead :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio[name='highlight']").on('change', function() {
    if ($('#radio7').prop("checked")) {
      $("#additional-service").addClass('shadow');
    } else {
      $("#additional-service").removeClass('shadow');
    }
  });

  $("input:radio[name='highlight']").on('change', function() {
    if ($('#radio8').prop("checked")) {
      $("#additional-service1").addClass('shadow');
    } else {
      $("#additional-service1").removeClass('shadow');
    }
  });

  $("input:radio[name='highlight']").on('change', function() {
    if ($('#radio9').prop("checked")) {
      $("#additional-service2").addClass('shadow');
    } else {
      $("#additional-service2").removeClass('shadow');
    }
  });
});
```